# Where does the money to make a video game come from?

Tags: costs, pricing

So 360/ps3 video games takes a few months to a few years to make I assume. If so where does the money to pay employees and costs of everything needed to make the game come from during those few months/few years?

Comment: Big publishers.

Comment: This is a _very_ pertinent question to the games industry in general, I really cannot understand why someone voted to close.

Comment: I voted to close when I first saw the question. While I thought it was a good question, I figured it would generate a list of answers, for all the different sources. It would be challenging to get a single *correct* answer. While it *is* generating a list, it's being contained to a single answer for now. As long as I can keep updating it with the additions I get in the comments :)

Comment: I do think it's answerable, there is a finite set of funding sources, especially if you keep them relatively general as you have.

Comment: I agree. That's why I tried my hand at making a general answer to try and set the tone and save the question.

Answer (score 20):

Depends on the game and the people making it. There are common sources for nearly any product being created, games aren't that different, but the below are tailored slightly more towards games:

- Publisher: A company that partners with a development studio to create a game. This is very much like an investor below, but the publisher will typically have considerably more control and influence over the final product.
- Investors: People or companies with money. They invest the money to make the game, they share in the profits.
- Capital from previous games: The game companies themselves fund the games with money they made from previous games.
- Personal funds: Indie devs often work for no money, have jobs on the side or burn through their savings while working on their game.
- Crowd sourcing - Kickstarter or similar sites allowing the crowd funding of games.
- Grants: Via the government of their country or various organizations promoting arts.
- Loans: Companies or individuals can take out a loan to pay for the development costs of a game (this is similar to investors, but with banks and likely more liability).

Comment: This is all true, but perhaps it's worth emphasising that for "360/PS3" games the question asks about, the most common one here is a specific type of 'investor' in the form of a traditional publisher.

Comment: From my knowledge, getting a loan for a game launch has been very difficult since the whole dot.com IT craze crash. Before then (at least in sweden) you could get loans for it. And yes, publishers tend to work as the investors for games, and usually they want a lot of pull for their money, so they can maximize their investments chance of panning out. See the kickstarter for double fine for instance.

Comment: I was also trying to emphasise that a publisher is a bit different from what we normally think of as an investor, in that they tend to take a more direct interest in what you create and how you create it. Investors are typically a lot more hands-off.

Comment: Don't forget, some countries (like NL) offer subsidy for several forms of artistic expressions, including artistic games. This won't get you a lot of money but all bits help.

Comment: In the EU, games are now seen as a cultural artifact, so particularly in the northern European countries (as I've seen) you will find that grants are actually given for the development of games -- pending review of your proposal, of course, since others will be competing for these grants. So @Thomas is correct.

Comment: This can go 2 ways, you can get a tax reduction, but you can also get money on your bank account. The amount of money received can never be larger then the amount of resources you (or your investors) bring in.

Comment: I've checked several resources, the amount you can get varies between €10.000 and €150.000 and cannot be greater then 50% of the total development cost. You don't need to bring in money, you can also bring in hours of work with a total value equal to the amount you receive. Sounds great right?

Comment: OK, I've added grants to the list. That does sound pretty great and appears to be a fairly significant amount of money.